# i want to put if condition when html loaded is there any way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('one').click(function(){
      if( loaded('new.html') ) {
        alert('yes');
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Is there any clear way to make it work?

Comment: Are you trying to check if some other page is loaded? $(document).ready fires when the current document is loaded, so I don't really understand what you are after.

Comment: You need to provide more information. How is new.html loaded?

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error. You have one superfluous `)` after the `if`.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your selector. Shouldn't `$('one')` be `$('#one')` for `id="one"` or `$('.one')` `class='one'`. Do you have an element `<one />`?

Comment: @Puuskis For what I've understood, on domready he just set the handler and when he clicks he want to know if the page has alredy fired the load event

Comment: i want if html file loaded in my website then i want to alert some,

Comment: What does "loaded in my website" means? could you edit your question and clarify more?

Answer (score 2):

You have some general misconceptions here. I'll start with the syntax/semantic errors in your code:

`$('one')` probably should be `#one` or `.one` depending if your element has an id or class.
An `if` condition only requires a closing `}`, you accidently added a `)`. If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) in your browser, you will see a console which tells you, if there are errors in your code.

Then it's not clear what you want to do.

In general when you want to check, if your html is ready, using the `ready` method (as you already did) is sufficient. You don't need to do any additional checks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* inside here, you can be sure your html is ready*/
});
```

Now it depends on what your code `loaded('new.html')` is exactly doing. But if you are loading `new.html` via ajax, you should use a success callback to work with the result. See [jQuery `get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more information about that.

In general all the code you want to execute after the `new.html` has loaded should be put into the callback.

```
var jqxhr = $.get("new.html", function() {
    alert("YES! Your html has successfully loaded");
    /* Put your code here*/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the $.get() function to load the page.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Looking at what you want, try this:

```
var isLoaded=false;

$(document).ready(function() {
   $.get('one.html', function(data) {
     isLoaded=true;
   });

   $('one').click(function(){
      if(isLoaded) {
        alert('yes');
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: JonRed my html file name is one.html , if i click any div then one.html is loading then show, here i need to put some if condition if one.html loaded then i want to alert (yes)

Comment: @AroraLight I've modified the answer to what I think you want.  Give it a go.